# HTML/CSS menu not working on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a website and I was happy that all was looking good on Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Then it came it suddenly in my mind, I started sweating, the heart started beating fast.. oh God, I have to test it on IE! And, of course, it doesn't work :)

So, I have a menu that looks like this:

[image]

and is created in this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>

        <title>Test &#8482;</title>

        <link href="styles/small.css" media="(max-width: 1000px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="styles/large.css" media="(min-width: 1000px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/test_logo.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="icon" href="images/test_logo.ico" type="image/ico" />
    </head>

    <body onload="setup()">
        <div id="menuContainer">
            <div id="menu">
                <img id="testLogo" alt="menu" src="images/test_write_black.png"/>

                <ul id="navimenu">
                    <li><a class="menuItem" id="homeMenuId"    onclick="homeClicked()"      >Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menuItem" id="supportMenuId" onclick="supportClicked()"   >Support</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menuItem" id="contribMenuId" onclick="contributeClicked()">Contribute</a></li>

                    <li><a id="languageText" href="#openModal">English</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                <div>
                    <a href="#close" class="close"><img id="imageClose" alt="delete" src="images/logo_delete_on.png"/></a>

                    <button class="language-selection" onclick="onChangeLanguageFunction('en')">English</button>
                    <button class="language-selection" onclick="onChangeLanguageFunction('it')">Italiano</button>
                    <button class="language-selection" onclick="onChangeLanguageFunction('de')">Deutsch</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ...
```

CSS:

```
.modalDialog
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target
{
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div
{
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 25px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 2px #be6500;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close
{
    background: Transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    top: -50px;
}
```

so when I click the "*language menu item*" on the right, the `modaDialog` shows up and I can choose the language.

On IE (tried 7/8/9/10) all is displayed correctly, but there's no hover (not a big problem), no "*finger mouse pointer*" and no *click functionality* on the menu items. But there are 3 "*finger mouse pointers*" circa 100px under the menu that change the language when clicked.

What could be the problem ? is there a tool to check what is wrong ?
I have already [validated](https://validator.w3.org/) the site and got 0 errors.

EDIT: following the CSS of the menu:

```
#menu
{
    height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:  middle;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: solid 2px #555555;
}

#menu ul
{
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#menu li
{
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
}

.menuItem
{
    color: #0000DD;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menuItem:hover
{
    color: #7777FF;
    font-weight: 2000;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 10px #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide the CSS code of the menu?

Comment: trying to go by step, I do not see any hover in your css (might be me) for anything. About the mouse pointer, is there any particular reason you use onclick and not a classic <a href="">

Comment: @Pierezzz: yes, sure, stupid me not posting it since the problem is in the menu. Done.

Comment: @keikoku92: I'm learning how to do a site while I'm doing it so, no, there's no good reason. I need to call a script function so I can highlight the current menu item, probably it can be done also through a href. BTW: I don't think this could be a cause of the problem, but I use php to create the html in a dynamic way.

Comment: @Malachi: I wrote that the finger cursor is not a big problem (the site will be viewed mostly from Android), the main problem is that the menu items are not clickable. Also, I cannot test till tomorrow as at home, obviously, I don't have Windows. Anyway, thanks, I'll try. `edit: the cursor works because under the menu, as I wrote, I can see 3 finger cursors (at the wrong place)`

Comment: The pointer: .menuItem { cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; } I believe it's 'hand' for lower versions of IE... just add it to your code and it should work.
Make sure that the .menuItem is an a.menuItem (be more specific.. it belongs to the a.. not sure why you use an a there, since it isn't really a link.. a span or div would work too). And use a padding of 0 in your li and move the padding that belongs to the li to the a.menuItem. It's easier to click on the link then... (clickable area is now bigger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that animating opacity in IE10 is not always very solid. It does not do anything and instead of animating opacity, you should animate visibility:

```
.modalDialog
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear; /* animation on visibility */
}

.modalDialog:target
{
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  transition-delay:0s;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7wfm162r/2/])

Comment: Thanks a lot, this explains the _why_. Later I will adapt it to my code and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, perfect, all works now on Chrome, FF, Safari and IE, my hero :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.
I write it as an answer because I solved the problem but I'd like someone to explain me WHY as I don't know.
In other words: this answer is only a hint to get to the right and acceptable answer.

For some unknown reason, IE doesn't like (or I don't know how he wants it) the `href="#id"`.
I had to substitute all the `href` with `onclick`.

So the menu is now like this:

```
<div id="menuContainer">
    <div id="menu">
        <img id="testLogo" alt="logo" src="images/test_write_black.png">

        <ul id="navimenu">
            <li class="menuItem"> <span id="homeMenuId"     onclick="homeClicked()"      >__HomeMenu__      </span></li>
            <li class="menuItem"> <span id="supportMenuId"  onclick="supportClicked()"   >__SupportMenu__   </span></li>
            <li class="menuItem"> <span id="contribMenuId"  onclick="contributeClicked()">__ContributeMenu__</span></li>
            <li id="languageText"><span id="languageMenuId" onclick="showLanguageMenu();">__language__      </span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <span class="close" onclick="hideLanguageMenu();"><img id="imageClose" alt="close" src="images/logo_delete_on.png"></span>

        <button class="languageSelection" onclick="onChangeLanguageFunction('en')">English </button>
        <button class="languageSelection" onclick="onChangeLanguageFunction('it')">Italiano</button>
        <button class="languageSelection" onclick="onChangeLanguageFunction('de')">Deutsch </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

modified the CSS file and added a:

```
#openModal
{
    display: none;
}
```

and added 2 *js* functions:

```
function showLanguageMenu()
{
    var langMenu = document.getElementById("openModal");
    langMenu.style.display = "block";
    langMenu.style.opacity = "1";
    langMenu.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
}

function hideLanguageMenu()
{
    var langMenu = document.getElementById("openModal");
    langMenu.style.display = "none";
    langMenu.style.opacity = "0";
    langMenu.style.pointerEvents = "none";
}
```

Works on IE and, of course, on Firefox and Chrome (still have to test on Safari).

But I've lost the nice fading effect and this is not good as it was really cute.

Comment: I created a JSFiddle of your code (https://jsfiddle.net/6johofmp/) but it works just fine in IE. Which even does not have the modified HTML yet. Can you check if that is also what you are seeing?

Comment: I'm using IE 10.0.9200.16721 on Windows 8 Pro 64bits and your jsfiddle is not working but works with Chrome and FF. Thanks. I'll try on other PCs.

Comment: @Pierezzz: IE 10 on Windows 7 (VM), same problem. What have you used   ?

Comment: to be sure, i only test if the modal dialog is working and if you see a nice fading effect. You can not  see that on your machine with IE??

Comment: Nope, [this](http://i.imgur.com/Q2C1zqZ.png "") is what I see and nothing is clickable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80154/discussion-between-pierezzz-and-marco).